# Applications Menu Icons Resize automatically

Tags: gnome, icons, 22.04, wayland

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. My Application Menu's icons change size when I open the app menu.

Sometimes, the icons are smaller:

[image]

After a few minutes, the icons can get bigger:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the icons from resizing like this?

Comment: did you get to fix it